# Get index of mutated Classname

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, observable

I got a list on a webpage.

After I press a button the system changes the class from `listFUTItem has-auction-data` to `listFUTItem has-auction-data won`.

I observe the list with a mutationobserver and want to get the index of the changed classelement.

I got no idea of how to get the index at all.

***At the webpage you only can have ONE `listFUTItem has-auction-data won`at once.*** I didnt know how to toggle it tbh. But thats not important here.

Here is a demo:

```js
$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('listFUTItem has-auction-data');
  $(this).addClass('listFUTItem has-auction-data won');
});

var observerTest = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
      if (
        attributeValue.includes("won")
      ) {
        console.log(attributeValue.index);
      }
    }
  });
});
observerTest.observe(document.body, {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

```css
.won {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can use `$(mutation.target).index()`.

```js
$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('won');
});

var observerTest = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log('mutation found');
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
      if (attributeValue.includes("won")) {
        console.log($(mutation.target).index());
      }
    }
  });
});

//Changed document.body to document.querySelector('.paginated') so it only observes this element (inclusing the subtree because of the settings), if you want to use jquery you can use $('.paginated').get(0).
observerTest.observe(document.querySelector('.paginated'), {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true
});

//Try to mimic the time problem as mentioned in the comments, howver it does not seem to trigger the mutation observer which makes sense since you are listening to attribute changes only.
window.setInterval(() => { document.querySelectorAll('.time').forEach(e => e.innerText = parseInt(e.innerText) + 1)}, 1000)
```

```css
.won {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack <span class=time>0<span>s</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann <span class=time>0<span>s</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique <span class=time>0<span>s</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos <span class=time>0<span>s</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen <span class=time>0<span>s</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I make it only firing once for it? At my web page it's nearly spamming me.

Comment: @Felix You trigger the log message twice because you first remove 2 classes and then add them again. You can change that by just adding the won class without removing and adding the others. Also you where observing `document.body`. If you only observe `.paginated` it will reduce the amount of triggers on other elements too. See my updated snippet.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Idk if I should make a new post. But what if there is a class `<div class"time"> 5sec / 4sec<div>` down of each  li elements? It will trigger all time when time is changing. Can I only observe the li classname of this 'parent' ?

Comment: @Felix Can you post a new question with the relevant code to reproduce your issue? I think you will need to listen to each mutations of the LI elements without Listening to the subtree.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.index()` method to get the index of the clicked `list-item`:

```
$('.listFUTItem.has-auction-data').index(this);
```

You can also remove `.won` from any `list-item` that may have it before adding it to the item clicked:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('won');
```

And if you want to be more specific:

```
$(this).siblings().filter('.won').removeClass('won');
```

```js
$('.listFUTItem').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().filter('.won').removeClass('won');
  $(this).addClass('listFUTItem has-auction-data won');
  console.log( $('.listFUTItem.has-auction-data').index(this) );
});

var observerTest = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
      if (
        attributeValue.includes("won")
      ) {
        console.log(attributeValue.index);
      }
    }
  });
});
observerTest.observe(document.body, {
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

```css
.won {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="paginated">
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Ballack</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Lehmann</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Pique</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Kroos</li>
  <li class="listFUTItem has-auction-data"> Owen</li>
</ul>
```